# libgit2sharp branch not found on freshly cloned repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, libgit2sharp, repo

libgit2sharp 0.21.0.176
C# on Windows Server 2008

I need to obtain reference to a specific branch.

On my Windows machine, I fresh git clone local repo from remote origin on GitHub.

Next I execute following `libgit2sharp` code :

```
var localRepo = new Repository({local-path},RepositoryOptions);
var remote = localRepo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", {remote-repo-uri);
localRepo.Network.Fetch(remote, FetchOptions, Signature, "performing fetch");
var branch = localRepo.Branches[{branch-name}];
```

But the branch is not present in the collection even though it exists on remote origin on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to git, only the default branch (or the one that has been specified in `CloneOptions.BranchName`) is created as a local head upon cloning.

Other branches are fetched, but only as remote tracking branches.

Two options:

- Given your remote is named "origin", you can access those remote tracking branches through`localRepo.Branches["origin/{branch-name}"];`
- You create a local branch and configure it to track its remote counterpart. See **[BranchFixture.CanSetUpstreamBranch()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/70d0c3b0ec244cfbe76232195400c86c47bb2577/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BranchFixture.cs#L768-L800)** test for an example of how to do this.